# How do I use trained .tfilte model, to create mask on live-camera output?

Tags: ios, swift, image-segmentation, tensorflow-lite

I've started learning ML on iOS with Swift. Now I know a little bit about neural networks. Here I have `.tflite` model well trained to recognize nails because the effect is like this:

[image]

Now I need to create a mask on live-camera output when

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {}
```

is called.

Currently when I put mask on live-camera there is an output like this:

[image]

What may be wrong with my model which interprets the output?

[Here](https://github.com/kunass2/naildetector) you can see my ScannerViewController used to preview a mask, and DeepLabModel.

**EDIT 1:**

If you have any other model, that can replace my DeepLabModel I also will be happy with this. Here is something wrong, and I don't know what.

**EDIT 2:**

I also think about possibility that the pod used in DeepLabModel is wrong:

```
pod 'TensorFlowLiteGpuExperimental'
```

Comment: CNN segmentations are not good enough yet to produce smooth boundaries as graph-based approaches. Could you supply the heart image and the network output?

Comment: Hi Bartlomiej...a lot of things may have gone wrong. Can you share .tflite file to check? Is it possible?

Comment: @Farmaker yes, I have updated github link.

Comment: With what version of TF have you trained model?

Comment: @Farmaker TensorFlow 2.0

Comment: I have analysed your .tflite file and the project from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android) and I have some questions. I do not know what is the best way to reach u because the comments here have limited characters

Comment: @Farmaker Ok, i am ready to answer;) If you help me to make it working I will give you some 500 bounties;) In my opinion library from cocoapod that I use is wrong: TensorFlow-experimental.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216258/discussion-between-farmaker-and-bartlomiej-semanczyk).

Comment: Hey! This is a bit off-topic, but where's `ProcessInputWithFloatModel` coming from? I'm trying to process my `CMSampleBuffer`s in realtime without copying them into byte arrays and just can't figure it out with the ObjC API...

Answer (score 1):

After analyzing your .tflite file that is hosted at your link above I can say that is well structured, it is giving 2 labels as you desire BUT it is not fully trained. I give you 3 pictures of the results after inference on android phone.

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]

So there is nothing wrong with your code... .tflite file is not producing good results!

My advice is to continue train it with more pictures of hands and nails. I would recommend over 300 pictures with masks of different hands and nails and about 30.000 epochs using [Deeplab](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab)

If you need a tool to help u with creating masks use [this](https://github.com/abreheret/PixelAnnotationTool)

You can always search [google](https://datasetsearch.research.google.com/search?query=voxceleb&docid=mzuawYn75YG48%2BTEAAAAAA%3D%3D) or [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets) for datasets to enhance the number of images you are using

If you need more info or anything else you can tag me!

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In Monday I am gonna check it along with the tool for creating masks. But my tool I currently use is not well prepared because mask import doesnt work, but I am gonna write to the developers. What is the number of epochs?

Comment: Hi Bartlomiej. Thanks for the reward of bounty. 1 Epoch = 1 Forward pass + 1 Backward pass for ALL training samples. Deeplab team usually train their models up to 30.000 epochs